# How to set a value in sidebarSearchForm widget

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using `sidebarSearchForm` widget from `shinnydashboard` package.

I would like to know if it is possible set an initial value for `shinnydashboard::sidebarSearchForm` like it is with `shinyWidgets::searchInput` using its `value` argument:

```
searchInput(
    inputId = "searchText",
    label = NULL,
    placeholder = "Write your opions",
    btnSearch = icon("magnifying-glass"),
    btnReset = icon("xmark"),
    value = 'Option 1',
    width = "100%"
  )
```

Comment: Based on the method description in the package, value='initial value' so you can set a default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `htmltools::tagAppendAttributes` or `htmltools::tagQuery` to inject a value attribute to the `sidebarSearchForm` (consisting of a text input and a button):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarUserPanel("User Name",
                   subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
                   # Image file should be in www/ subdir
                   image = "userimage.png"
  ),
  tagAppendAttributes(sidebarSearchForm(label = "Enter a number", "searchText", "searchButton"), value = "my initial value", .cssSelector = "input"),
  sidebarMenu(
    # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new",
             badgeColor = "green"),
    menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
             menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("dashboard",
            div(p("Dashboard tab content"))
    ),
    tabItem("widgets",
            "Widgets tab content"
    ),
    tabItem("subitem1",
            "Sub-item 1 tab content"
    ),
    tabItem("subitem2",
            "Sub-item 2 tab content"
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```